# Error with huge list of AD groups. Not giving output

Tags: powershell

I am trying to automate a powerbi report using AD data. I was doing a test on this code and it will give me a good output that I need for a couple of groups. But I was trying to run this with 250K list of groups and I am getting this error. I tried couple of times and it takes a lot of time and it was not giving me any output.

**Error**
Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): "The
parameter is incorrect.  "

**Note:** All attributes are generic and no custom attributes

```
$groupUsersList = Get-Content $Path
$tableStorage = @()

$groupUsersList |  ForEach-Object { 
    $GroupProperties = get-adgroup $_ -prop *
   
        $table = new-object psobject
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Name -NotePropertyValue  $GroupProperties.Name
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName GroupCategory -NotePropertyValue $GroupProperties.GroupCategory
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Owner -NotePropertyValue $GroupProperties.extensionAttribute12.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0] 
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName OwnerinfoID -NotePropertyValue  $GroupProperties.info.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0]}
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName InCloud -NotePropertyValue  $GroupProperties.InCloud
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Created -NotePropertyValue  $GroupProperties.Created
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Owner2 -NotePropertyValue $GroupProperties.BusinessOwner.Split("=")[1].Split(",")[0]
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Description -NotePropertyValue  $GroupProperties.Description
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Owner3 -NotePropertyValue  $GroupProperties.info   
        $table | Add-Member -NotePropertyName atttrib12 -NotePropertyValue  $GroupProperties.extensionAttribute12
        $tableStorage += $table
}

$tableStorage |  Export-Csv -Path $output'.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

**output:**
Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect.  "

Comment: Are `InCloud` and `BusinessOwner` custom attributes on your domain?? I don't think those are generic attributes for `AD Groups`

Comment: hello @SantiagoSquarzon, There are no customs on my attributes. I just renamed it here since there is a company name. But all of the attributes are just directly from the AD groups

Comment: I mean this `$GroupProperties.InCloud` and this `$GroupProperties.BusinessOwner`. Are you sure if you do `Get-ADGroup exampleGroup -Properties InCloud, BusinessOwner` you don't get an error?

Comment: Yes @SantiagoSquarzon. I'm getting data from those attributes when I run it on a small amount of grouplists.

Comment: The only error that I was getting is this "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" if the column is empty since I was parsing some data from some field using split.

Comment: That error is probably comming from your `split` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code instead, it should be faster than what you're doing. In addition, it should help you understand the errors you're getting.

As you said, you were getting the `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression` exception. One possible way you're getting this exception is for example, let's assume that the value for `$adGroup.info` is this:

```
$string = 'This is the group information without the equal sign'
```

Now if we try to split the `string` as you're doing:

```
$string.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0]
```

You would get that exact same error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $string.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0]
```

#### Code

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$groupUsersList = Get-Content $Path
$destinationPath = "$HOME\Documents\output.csv"
$tableStorage = [system.collections.generic.list[pscustomobject]]::new()

foreach($group in $groupUsersList)
{
    if([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($group))
    {
        continue
    }

    try
    {
        $hash = @{
            Identity = $group
            Properties = @(
                'inCloud','BusinessOwner'
                'extensionAttribute12','Info'
                'Created','Description'
            )
        }

        $adGroup = Get-ADGroup @hash
    }
    catch
    {
        Write-Warning $_
        continue
    }

    try
    {
        $businessOwner = $adGroup.BusinessOwner.Split("=")[1].Split(",")[0]
    }
    catch
    {
        'Can't split this: {0}' -f $adGroup.BusinessOwner
        $businessOwner = $adGroup.BusinessOwner
    }
    
    try
    {
        $info = $adGroup.info.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0]
    }
    catch
    {
        'Can't split this: {0}' -f $adGroup.info 
        $info = $adGroup.info
    }

    try
    {
        $owner = $adGroup.extensionAttribute12.Split("=")[1].split(",").split("|")[0]
    }
    catch
    {
        'Can't split this: {0}' -f $adGroup.extensionAttribute12
        $owner = $adGroup.extensionAttribute12
    }

    $tableStorage.Add(
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $adGroup.Name
            GroupCategory = $adGroup.GroupCategory
            Owner = $owner
            OwnerinfoID = $info 
            InCloud = $adGroup.InCloud
            Created = $adGroup.Created
            Owner2 = $businessOwner
            Description = $adGroup.Description
            Owner3 = $adGroup.info   
            atttrib12 = $adGroup.extensionAttribute12
    })
}

if($tableStorage)
{
    $tableStorage | Export-Csv -Path $destinationPath -NoTypeInformation -Force
    "CSV Exported successfully to $destinationPath"
}
```

#### A few points to consider

- Adding items to `System.Array` `@()` is a lot slower than adding items to a `collections.generic.list`.
- Creating objects with new `psobject` + `Add-Member` is a lot slower than casting objects with `pscustomobject`.
- Calling **ALL** properties on `Get-ADGroup` `-Properties *` is a lot slower than calling only the properties you need `-Properties prop1,prop2,prop3`.

Comment: Thank you so much Santiago, It totally works now and I see what you are saying. Its very big help for me in the future! Thank you so much

Comment: No problem @Den10102020 I'm glad it helped you :) working with AD is a very nice opportunity to learn PS scripting

Comment: I changed all of my scripts on storing in collections.generic.list. I tested it and its better and fast than before.